# How to show Nested Object Fields in Django CoreAPI documentation

Tags: django-rest-framework, core-api

Generic View for Employee :

```
class EmployeeCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
```

I have a nested Employee serializer.

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('user','employee_position','join_date')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Overriding the default create method of the Model serializer.
        :param validated_data: data containing all the details of student
        :return: returns a successfully created student record
        """

        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = UserSerializer.create(UserSerializer(), validated_data=user_data)
        employee, created = Employee.objects.update_or_create(user=user,
                            join_date=validated_data.pop('join_date'),
                            employee_position=validated_data.pop('employee_position'))
        return employee
```

Now When I am trying to display this API in Docs :

[image]

So I want to display fields for User too. 
Is it possible to customize this?

Comment: Do you want to see list of users or add a new user?

Comment: I want to add user @MohammadAli. So it should show all the fields for User too

Comment: write UserSerializer and Employee model please

Comment: Did you see the result in a browser or in Post app

Comment: I can post it. I have no issues in that. I just wanted to show in API documentation which fields are included in User object.

Comment: I also referred to this : https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5072

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proper way of achieving what you want is to make a User creation endpoint separately and then have a field for user in Employee Serializer using the Primary Key Related field.
This specific situation arose when i was doing my internship and believe me, you don't want to use directly nested User Serializer as this will give problem when you try to make API for updating an Employee, because the control of creating the User gets shifted to the Employee endpoint.
That way, you first create the user and then while registering Employee can assign the proper user according to the Primary Key.

Comment: But the one you said is similar to oneToOne relationship. Which I did already.

Comment: What primary key related field is to designate the target of the relationship. How it will work is while creating an employee you give in the primary key of the user that you want the employee to assigned. Its alright if the relationship between employee and user is one to one. Try what I have said and it will work for sure. I have already handled similar cases using just what I told.

Comment: Can we have a deeply conversation on this ? I am really new to django . So You can suggest me a better database design just for managing users, customer and employee in an efficient way.

Comment: Okay. See the main thing is ultimately all the customer and employee are user only. So the database schema is pretty straight forward. Just make 3 different models. User, customer and employee. And then work out whatever relationship you have in mind for them. And do mark the tick and upvote the answer, if you believe it answers your questions. I will be happy to help further.